# Reluctance Motor Load Angle

Tags: power, motor

I am building an invention ([WIPO Patent W02020172689](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2020172689&_cid=P21-KK1JL1-55091-1)) to control the pitch of a fan/propeller/turbine blade that uses a thread applied to the rotating system and a nut threadedly mated to that rotating system; the nut has radial protrusions and is made out of a ferromagnetic material -- it is spun using electromagnets which are switched off and on using the logic levels of a gear tooth sensor disposed near the threaded nut's radial protrusions.  I need to position two gear teeth sensors at angles in relation to the electromagnets so that I can create logic levels that will turn off and on when I can maximizing the reluctance torque.

I have read through journal articles looking for a torque vs angle plot to help guide this decision.  I believe the terminology for this is the "load angle."  This [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjck66L3aPuAhU2GFkFHdJ0CsIQFjAAegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs00202-019-00775-z&usg=AOvVaw0LOJUtOo4RZViLOKB-rz2G) displays this plot:
[image: Calculated and measured static torque characteristics for 6/4 topology; constant current 16A]

Is it a correct inference to say that torque is maximized when the rotor pole's angle in relation to the stator pole is maximized for a 6/4 configuration when "this" angle is between 10 and 25 degrees?

Comment: I would say that is correct. I might say 6/4 "stator/rotor pole configuration" rather than "topology."

Comment: "Load angle" is also known as "torque angle."

Comment: Is this induction start reluctance run variant?

Comment: Not sure what that means.  The reluctance config is for pitch manipulation.  A second motor is needed to spin the fan

Comment: The second motor already has things spinning so the pitch control reluctance config has none of the normal reluctance startup problems